# Objective C: Accessing properties of an object instance that's in an array that's a property of an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, properties, casting

This seems like it would be a simple thing to do but I'm having trouble finding the exact syntax.

I have an object called myObject.  It has a property called companies.  Each object in that array is an object of type Company which has a property called myid.  I'm simply trying to access the myid property (which is an NSString) similar to:

```
NSLog(@"My id: %@", myObject.companies[0].myid);
```

Xcode advises that above is not correct and should be changed to:

```
NSLog(@"My id: %@", myObject->companies[0].myid);
```

This produces an error "Property 'myid' not found for object type 'id'".

SO, I tried casting the result to the proper type, Company, with this:

```
NSLog(@"My id: %@", myObject->(Company *)companies[0].myid);
```

This gives me an "expected identifier" error at the second parenthesis.  I've tried several other variants with no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: I found it can be done using the older bracket notation and objectAtIndex like this:     NSLog(@"My id: %@", [[myObject.companies objectAtIndex:0 ] myid ]);

Comment: But I'd like to find a way to do it via dot notation. I'd also like to be able to SET these values this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((Company*)myObject.companies[0]).myId
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a cleaner and more readable code as the following

```
Company *company =  myObject.companies[0];
NSLog(@"My id: %@", company.myid);
```

Comment: I'm doing it this way in various other parts of the code, using temporary variables, but this actually makes it much messier.